# Where can I find a fire truck?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I am working on gathering items for a heist and I need a firetruck. I tried setting a car on fire with a jerrycan, but no fire trucks were dispatched.  I have looked near multiple hospitals as well.

Where can I find one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call 911 (located in your contacts).

This is the easiest way to get hold of police cars, firetrucks and ambulances.

Comment: :O I didnt know that! awesome!  I will try it.  Thanks.

Comment: Yep this worked.  I just called 911 and selected fire department.  Thanks again.

Comment: Lester actually tells you this in a dialog (bla bla bla, call 911 bla bla bla).